# Access problem in local class

Tags: c++, scope, local-class

```
void foobar(){
    int local;
    static int value;
     class access{
           void foo(){
                local = 5; /* <-- Error here */
                value = 10;
           }
     }bar;    
}   
void main(){
  foobar();
}
```

Why doesn't access to `local` inside `foo()` compile? OTOH I can easily access and modify the static variable `value`.

Comment: The return type of `main()` must always be `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a local class you cannot use/access auto variables from the enclosing scope. You can use only static variables, extern variables, types, enums and functions from the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

From standard docs *Sec 9.8.1*,

> A class can be declared within a function definition; such a class is called a local class. The name of a local class is local
>   to its enclosing scope. The local class is in the scope of the enclosing scope, and has the same access to names outside
>   the function as does the enclosing function. Declarations in a local class **can use only type names, static variables,
>   extern variables and functions, and enumerators from the enclosing scope.**

An example from the standard docs itself,

```
int x;
void f()
{
static int s ;
int x;
extern int g();
struct local {
int g() { return x; } // error: x is auto
int h() { return s; } // OK
int k() { return ::x; } // OK
int l() { return g(); } // OK
};
// ...
}
```

Hence accessing an auto variable inside a local class is not possible. Either make your local value as `static` or a global one, whichever looks *appropriate* for your design.

Answer (score 0):

Make `local` static and then you should be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you can declare object that lives out of scope of the function.

```
foobar() called // local variable created;
Access* a = new Access(); // save to external variable through interface
foobar() finished // local variable destroyed

...


savedA->foo(); // what local variable should it modify?
```