# Why can't local classes access variables from the enclosing scope?

Tags: c++

[A local class cannot access local variables of the function in which it is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3930239/560648).

Why is this? What is the reason for this rule in C++?

Comment: First Learn What Is A Scope Of A Variable.

Comment: I know scope of a variabe,this is a restriction that is put on local class by the author of C++,so get your facts straight first.

Comment: In C++, classes don't inherit scope like Java classes do.

Comment: @tkausl Yet global variables are visible inside classes. So the question is why is there a restriction for local variables.

Comment: May be it can be an exception made by the author of C++ but the question is why he made this exception ?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting so many down-votes. Sure, it may be difficult to find an authoritative answer here, but it doesn't make this a bad question. And it doesn't mean an authoritative, non-speculative answer doesn't exist.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @ShankarShastri: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3930204/560648

Comment: @juanchopanza: There's not much meat to it, but I don't really know what more meat there could be. Anyway, I've edited out the equivocation and tidied it up a bit; perhaps that'll help.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reasonable question to ask, especially since some common languages, e.g. Python, allow this.

However, think about this situation if references to locals were allowed and hypothetically this code could compile.

```
struct MyClass {
    virtual fetchValue() = 0;
};

MyClass* somefunction(){
    int localVariable = 123;
    struct HypotheticalClass : public MyClass {
        virtual int fetchValue(){ return localVariable; }
    };
    return new HypotheticalClass()
}
```

Now, upon returning this MyClass derivative at the end of somefunction(), it maintains reference to a now-invalid stack location.  Boom.

Of course there is a multitude of other ways to inappropriately reference invalid stack locations, for example, passing a reference to that local variable to your class to get the access anyway.  And the same issue exists for lambdas which can have access to the local reference or do a copy.

As for an authoritative answer as to why, I skimmed through 4th edition Stroustrup and see nothing useful to report.

Thanks for the interesting question.